# Floppy drive only works one way

Tags: floppy

I have no trouble copying files from the floppy drive but when I try to drag files to the floppy drive they move right back to the source folder without being copied. These are small files, well within the capacity of the floppy disk. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just for topicality's sake - what version of ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

Man, its been years since I used a floppy disk.

I would check if the write protect tab is in the correct position, and try with another disk to ensure that it is not a problem with the drive.

[image]

(I'm assuming this is a 3 1/4 inch floppy. If its a 5 1/2 inch floppy it needs to be covered by tape, and if its an 8 inch floppy, it belongs in a museum.)